# Отслеживание слайдов в ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs

Есть `ViewPager` с 4 страницами, каким методом можно отследить переход от одного таба к другому?

Нужно это для того, чтобы при "закрытии" таба значения из `Edittext` сохранялись в БД.
Например: на экране отображается вкладка `Users`, слайдом, или тап-ом мы переходим в вкладку `System`(вкладка `Users` закрывается), То значения `Edittext`ов и `checkbox`ов сохраняются в БД(там будет реализовано через `db.update()`.

Вот ищу что то похожее на `addTextChangeListener`

Вот вид приложения:

[image: Users]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вам в помощь `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()`:

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Если в onPageScrolled вызывать `EditText` и получать из них информацию - приложение вылетает с nullPointer(тоисть оно сначало вызывает onPageScrolled, а потом уже весь View странички. Как побороть можна?

Comment: вы используете фрагменты?

Comment: в любом случае вам необходимо инициализировать `EditText` до  пролистывания